# How to secure unprotected Telnet Server on Droid 3

Tags: firewalls, mobile, android

I have a Droid 3 and for whatever reason it has a Telnet Server running on port 23. It requires no credentials and it has root permissions. It bothers me when I'm connected to wifi networks because my phone would be extremely easy to hack into. Here are the options I'm thinking about:

1. Disable the Telnet Server
2. Password protect the Telnet Server
3. Put up a firewall to make the port inaccessible

I'm not sure what is the best course of action in this case, I'm sure disabling the server is the safest but I'm not sure exactly sure how to do that. How can I protect my phone from being hacked into from this Telnet server?

Comment: The Droid 3 does not have this by default, it sounds like you rooted your phone, I would reverse that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't immediately test this, but it should be either of these:

- /etc/init.d/telnetd stop
- /etc/xinit.d/telnetd stop

You need to have a shell, there are terminal emulators for free in the playstore.

Comment: I tried both of those, the system cant find init.d or xinit.d, i also tried doing ps telnetd, which gave me the PID, then i tried kill (PID). I also tried telnetd stop, which gets hung up and waits forever. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the device have iptables installed?

Comment: @Polynomial i've never heard of it before, how do i check for that?

Comment: I found the telnetd file in system/bin/ and i deleted it, it fixed the problem, thanks for the help!